# Not able to add .ashx file in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I recently downloaded Visual Studio 2012 for web(express edition) and I am creating a simple asp .net empty web site. I am retreiving the data from mysql database by using Websockets. For that i want to add .ashx file to my solution but when i am hitting add new item it is not giving me the option to add .ashx file(handler file).

edited--
all the option i am getting for adding a new file are
Text File
html page
style sheet
xml file 
xml schema
xslt file
sql file

Comment: The file type is called Generic Handler. you aren't just overlooking it by looking for htings that stat with H are you?

Comment: thanx for replying but this option is not there

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The item is listed as "Generic Handler"

It is also just a file type and if you can't add it you can just add an html page. When adding call it something like Handler.ashx.

Then copy and paste the default handler code, and rebuild.

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Visual Sudio will stop yelling at you and underlining things once you rebuild and close/reopen the new .ashx file.

If it still has issues something is wacked up somewhere. If you have older versions of studio see if it will let you create a .ashx there. Then maybe import it?

**EDIT-Visual Studio Command Prompt for Missing Templates**

You can run Visual Studio Command promt and look into `devenv' if you are missing templates but have them in the templates directories. They may just need to be installed.

```
devenv /installvstemplates
```

Answer (score 10):

Try to add "Web">"C#">"Generic Handler" file

Comment: i am not getting this option

Comment: Hi @arjun,
Try to add "Visual c#" -> "Web" -> "Generic Handler"

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2015:

- Right click on the project
- Select Add... New Item
- You will find it under under Visual C#, Web tree on the left.
- Select Generic Handler on the right
- Give it a name, such as Handler1.ashx.

Comment: This answer is worked for me but it is not clear how to "Give it a name".  The UI does not allow naming it; it just has an "Open" button.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open visual Studio Installer.
2. Click Modify.
3. click "ASP.Net and web development" so that it is checked.
4. In the "Installation Details" section (on the Right), you will see an "Optional" section. Make sure that ".Net Framework project and item templates" is checked.
5. Click "Modify"

Comment: This is the correct answer even for Community 2022.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking in Visual C# Templates->Web

It should be here -> [image: Handler.ashx]

Answer (score 1):

[According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx) you can use following command to install/restore/organize **project templates**:

```
devenv /installvstemplates
```

And you can use following command to install/restore/organize **item templates**:

```
devenv /setup
```

To run the commands you need to locate the directory that contains *devenv.exe* --which is usually located at

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
```

Note that path may be different due to different VS versions.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue of not having many options to "Add".  Turns out there are different options if you happen to be debugging the project at the time, just something to keep in mind.